# What is a way to create a TF-IDF column in my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp, tf-idf

I have a pandas dataframe where all preprocessed columns of my tweets (tokens, cleaned, lemma, sentiments) are in.

I have made a TF-IDF array, but I cannot seem to make a new column in my existing pd where it shows all values of my TF-IDF, to be ready for a row means.

I have tried:

```
lm_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(lm.toarray())
lm_tfidf.head()
```

but it only made a dataframe of 5 x 14540 sparse matrix.

I just do not know what to do for this.

This is the Google Colab of the whole program:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YNfrwtAK6J8v2V3DQ7EEJ_XxCS8PeC99?usp=sharing

And if you cannot see the Google Colab because of slow loading, here is the printed PDF of the whole .ipynb:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZXbxCJES5fyIJWSTsWh9GhkRCUfUkw9g/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your sentences are stored in `sentences` column inside a `df` so you can do this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd
sentences = ['this is the first document',
          'this document is the second document',
          'and this is the third one',
          'is this the first document']
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentences':sentences})

pipe = Pipeline([('count', CountVectorizer()),
                 ('tfid', TfidfTransformer())])
df['TFIDF'] = pipe.fit_transform(df['sentences']).toarray().tolist()
df
```

output:

```
    sentences   TFIDF
0   this is the first document  [0.0, 0.46979138557992045, 0.5802858236844359,...
1   this document is the second document    [0.0, 0.6876235979836938, 0.0, 0.2810886740337...
2   and this is the third one   [0.511848512707169, 0.0, 0.0, 0.26710378764216...
3   is this the first document  [0.0, 0.46979138557992045, 0.5802858236844359,...
```